# Complexity of circuit evaluation in Resolution

Tags: proof-complexity, circuits, encoding, resolution

Consider the standard evaluation function for CNF formulas $\mathsf{Eval}(\varphi,x)$ taking as input a CNF $\varphi$ and an assignment $x$ to the variables and outputting the value of $\varphi(x)$.

Now, let $\varphi$ be an unsatisfiable CNF that the Resolution proof system can refute in size $s$. Can it also refute, in size $s^{O(1)}$, the CNF encoding of $\mathsf{Eval}(\varphi,x)$, obtained in the usual way using extension variables for each gate of the circuit? In other words, does the $\mathsf{Eval}$ function (or the conversion to CNF of that circuit) obfuscate the unsatisfiability of a formula $\varphi$, given that Resolution could easily see that it was unsatisfiable?

If this is not true for Resolution, what is the weakest proof system for which this holds true? I'd imagine strong systems like Extended Frege can immediately identify that $\varphi(x)$ and $\mathsf{Eval}(\varphi,x)$ are the same thing, but I could see this failing for Resolution.

Comment: Is your encoding of Eval() just a new variable equivalent to each clause, plus another variable equivalent to the conjunction of all new variables, which is additionally forced to true? It seems you should be able to recover your original formula from that in a linear amount of resolution steps in the size of the formula, but perhaps I am missing something.